# Why does the string change when using python split?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
test_str = "Question: The cryptocurrency Bitcoin Cash (BCH/USD) settled at 1368 USD at 07:00 AM UTC at the Bitfinex exchange on Monday, April 23. In your opinion, will BCH/USD trade above 1500 USD (+9.65%) at anу timе bеfore Арril 28? Indicаtоr: 60.76%"

print(test_str)
print(test_str.split('before '))
```

This the output I get after spliting

```
"['Question: The cryptocurrency Bitcoin Cash (BCH/USD) settled at 1368 USD at 07:00 AM UTC at the Bitfinex exchange on Monday, April 23. In your opinion, will BCH/USD trade above 1500 USD (+9.65%) at an\xd1\x83 tim\xd0\xb5 b\xd0\xb5fore \xd0\x90\xd1\x80ril 28? Indic\xd0\xb0t\xd0\xber: 60.76%']"
```

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/VitalOrganicBackups

Comment: Disclaimer: this is a copy of a question just asked (and deleted) by @Aditya. I did not agree with the conclusion in comments and I ask it again here.

Comment: It's just a different representation of your string and may be related to your IDE's encoding. For me it shows the result as expected.

Comment: You tag the question as both Python 3 and Python 2. The issue only shows up in Python 2 though. Please be clear about which version you're using.

Comment: Moreover, the string is not split into two, indicating that there are non-standard (ASCII) characters in your string. Obviously the encoded ones. These turn out to be Cyrillic ones. (y, e, b, a, in various places in the string).

Comment: @Evert: I know that. Simply the comments in the original question proposed other (wrong IMHO) reasons, and I wanted to give a correct answer. For >10k users the original question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49997466/3545273)

Comment: A deleted question may be reopened, or linked to for +10K rep people; that might have been less confusing. Using the right tag (i.e., improving the original question) also helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by a mix of Latin and Cyrillic characters. They print exactly the same in most policies, but are still different characters and do have different codes.

The output in the question is for Python 2.7 (what original question asker used) but it is easy to have equivalent behaviour in Python 3:

```
>>> print(test_str.encode('UTF8'))
b'Question: The cryptocurrency Bitcoin Cash (BCH/USD) settled at 1368 USD at 07:00 AM UTC at the Bitfinex exchange on Monday, April 23. In your opinion, will BCH/USD trade above 1500 USD (+9.65%) at an\xd1\x83 tim\xd0\xb5 b\xd0\xb5fore \xd0\x90\xd1\x80ril 28? Indic\xd0\xb0t\xd0\xber: 60.76%'
```

The unicodedata module helps to better understand what actually happens:

```
>>> for i in b'\xd1\x83\xd0\xb5\xd0\x90\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe'.decode('utf8'):
    print(i, hex(ord(i)), i.encode('utf8'), unicodedata.name(i))
```

```
у 0x443 b'\xd1\x83' CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER U
е 0x435 b'\xd0\xb5' CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER IE
А 0x410 b'\xd0\x90' CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER A
р 0x440 b'\xd1\x80' CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ER
о 0x43e b'\xd0\xbe' CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER O
```

So the original text contains cyrillic letters and for comparisons, they are not the same of their latin equivalent, even if they print the same. The problem has nothing to do with split but is just a poor original string.

Comment: so how do you solve something like this, given that you have no control on the input string...

Answer (score 1):

Decoding the string using "UTF-8"

```
print test_str.decode("utf-8")
u'Question: The cryptocurrency Bitcoin Cash (BCH/USD) settled at 1368 USD at 07:00 AM UTC at the Bitfinex exchange on Monday, April 23. In your opinion, will BCH/USD trade above 1500 USD (+9.65%) at an\u0443 tim\u0435 b\u0435fore \u0410\u0440ril 28? Indic\u0430t\u043er: 60.76%'
```

As it still has some non-ASCII characters (such as [CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER U](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0443/index.htm)), we can translate it further. Full list here: [Cyrillic Script Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode)

Using [unidecode](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/)

```
import unidecode
unidecode.unidecode(test_str.decode("utf-8"))
'Question: The cryptocurrency Bitcoin Cash (BCH/USD) settled at 1368 USD at 07:00 AM UTC at the Bitfinex exchange on Monday, April 23. In your opinion, will BCH/USD trade above 1500 USD (+9.65%) at anu time before Arril 28? Indicator: 60.76%'
unidecode.unidecode(test_str.decode("utf-8")).split("before ")
['Question: The cryptocurrency Bitcoin Cash (BCH/USD) settled at 1368 USD at 07:00 AM UTC at the Bitfinex exchange on Monday, April 23. In your opinion, will BCH/USD trade above 1500 USD (+9.65%) at anu time ',
 'Arril 28? Indicator: 60.76%']
```

Note: If you do not want to use unidecode, I found this article explains another way in much detail: [Transliterating non-ASCII characters with Python](https://programminghistorian.org/lessons/transliterating)

Comment: Beware unidecode decode the letter depending on what it represents while here the string uses it for what it prints like. For example the CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ER will become a `r` when it prints like a `p`. Anyway a variation of `unidecode` is probably the way to go...